# Fill missing values when aggregating a time series from minutes to hours

Tags: time-series, forecasting, missing-data, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am attempting to predict future values using AWS Forecast, and my data is by minute.  However, due to data size constraints, I need to aggregate this data to hourly.

The problem is that I am missing values for several minutes within an hour.  This can range from missing just one minute of the hour to missing 59 minutes.  I thought I could sample from the values that I do have that match on hour of day and day of the week (these are the two most important seasonalities in the data) to fill in the missing values but filling in 59 minutes of an hour this way feels too extreme.  Plus I'm not really feeding the model any new information at that point.

I think this might be a subjective question but what would you consider an appropriate cutoff of the fraction of missing minutes to just set the entire hour to missing?  I don't have a ton of data to begin with so I really want to try and salvage as much as I can.  For example, if I have 20 minutes of data but am missing the other 40 minutes, would sampling to fill the missing values still be appropriate?

Comment: Why not treat it as an [tag:unevenly-spaced-time-series]? If so, you can add that tag!

Comment: Thank you!  I have done so.